# ValueProvider<String> is not getting accepted by the pipeline for BigTable's InstanceID and TableID

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to write to BigTable through a generic Dataflow code. By generic I mean it must be able to write to any BigTable table provided as a parameter at runtime, using a ValueProvider.
The code is not showing any errors but when I try to create a template of the code, I can see below error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value only available at runtime, but accessed from a non-runtime context: RuntimeValueProvider{propertyName=bigTableInstanceId, default=null}
```

It is weird as the functionality to give ValueProviders is supported for this.

Below is the code I am using to write to BigTable:

```
results.get(btSuccessTag).apply("Write to BigTable",
                    CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(new CloudBigtableTableConfiguration.Builder()
                            .withProjectId(options.getProject())
                            .withInstanceId(options.getBigTableInstanceId())
                            .withTableId(options.getBigTableTable())
                            .build()));
```

The interface defining the ValueProviders is:

```
public interface BTPipelineOptions extends DataflowPipelineOptions{
    @Required
    @Description("BigTable Instance Id")
    ValueProvider<String> getBigTableInstanceId();
    void setBigTableInstanceId(ValueProvider<String> bigTableInstanceId);

    @Required
    @Description("BigTable Table Destination")
    ValueProvider<String> getBigTableTable();
    void setBigTableTable(ValueProvider<String> bigTableTable);

    @Required
    @Description("BT error file path")
    ValueProvider<String> getBTErrorFilePath();
    void setBTErrorFilePath(ValueProvider<String> btErrorFilePath);
}
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: Can you put the code snippet where you are defining the value providers?

Comment: Does it work if you use `options.getBigTableInstanceId().get()`?

Comment: @GuillemXercavins No, that won't work as we're not allowed to access it pre-runtime.

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman I've updated the post with the snippet of the interface defining the ValueProviders.

Comment: You can take a look at - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/bigtable/AvroToBigtable.java

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the error? Where is the error actually occurring?

Comment: looking at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates  should your code not be " ValueProvider<String> getBigTableTable();
    void setBigTableTable(ValueProvider<String> value);"

Comment: @kenn knowles it occurs exactly at the point where I try to write to bigtable. I mean even the template does not get created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that the **CloudBigtableIO** parameters are not updated to be modified by templates via a ValueProvider. Though **BigtableIO** is compatible with ValueProviders.

In order for Dataflow templates to be able to modify a parameter when launched from template, the library transforms (i.e. the source and sinks) it uses must be first updated to user ValueProviders for the parameters all the way into the library code, when the parameter is used. See more details about [ValueProvider](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates) here.

However, we have example template pipelines which work with BigtableIO instead of CloudBigtableIO. See [AvroToBigtable](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/bigtable/AvroToBigtable.java). So I think that you have a few options

1. Update your custom pipeline, using one of the [Bigtable template examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/bigtable) as an example to follow. Be sure to use BigtableIO instead of CloudBigtableIO
2. Update CloudBigtableIO to use ValueProviders all the way through, until the parameter is used. See [creating_templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates), and an example of proper ValueProvider usage in [BigtableIO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b446304f75078ca9c97437e685409c31ceab7503/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableIO.java#L225). Contribute it to apache beam's github, or extend/modify the class locally.
3. See if the existing Bigtable template pipelines fit your needs. You can [launch them from the Dataflow UI](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates).

I hope this works for you. Let me know if I explained this well. Or if I overlooked something.

Comment: Hi I've changed the code now to use BigTableIO. It works.